# How to draw lines between two image layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am trying to create layout which has four buttons.

I have managed to show the four image buttons but I couldn't show separating lines. In the following image you can see what I am trying to design:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative layout and add View objects first to separate them (see below).  You'll have to add whatever other parameters you want...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width          = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height         = "match_parent">

    <View
        android:id                      = "@+id/vertical_divider"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
        android:layout_width            = "1dip"
        android:layout_height           = "match_parent">
    </View>

    <View
        android:id                      = "@+id/horizontal_divider"
        android:layout_centerVertical   = "true"
        android:layout_width            = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height           = "1dip">
    </View>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_alignParentTop   = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft  = "true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf         = "@id/vertical_divider"
        android:layout_above            = "@id/horizontal_divider"
        android:layout_width            = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height           = "match_parent">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_alignParentTop   = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_toRightOf        = "@id/vertical_divider"
        android:layout_above            = "@id/horizontal_divider"
        android:layout_width            = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height           = "match_parent">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft   = "true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf          = "@id/vertical_divider"
        android:layout_below             = "@id/horizontal_divider"
        android:layout_width             = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height            = "match_parent">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight  = "true"
        android:layout_toRightOf         = "@id/vertical_divider"
        android:layout_below             = "@id/horizontal_divider"
        android:layout_width             = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height            = "match_parent">
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `layout_marginBottom="1dip"` and `layout_marginRight="1dip"` in your `Imageviews`.